# Beautiful Soup only returns last value of table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

I am trying to **scrape** table data from [this page](https://www.pgatour.com/content/pgatour/stats/stat.02674.y2020.eon.t027.html) on the PGA stats website. I am grabbing the player name, and the code seems to be working, but it only returns the last value "Patrick Rodgers" from the site. What am I doing wrong here?

This is the  [html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYla1.png) it's grabbing.

Here is my source code:

```
#Get URL and Parse
url = 'https://www.pgatour.com/content/pgatour/stats/stat.02674.y2020.eon.t027.html'
results = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, 'html.parser')

#Find data
sg_ttg = soup.find('table', id = 'statsTable')

#Get data
for player in sg_ttg.find_all('tbody'):
    rows = player.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        playername = row.find('td', class_= 'player-name').text
```

Comment: You are using same variable name in the last 2 for loops for 2 things.

Comment: I noticed that right after posting, so instead of player = row.find... I changed the variable to player_nm, but it is still only returning the last value.

Comment: how are you storing your data. When you do `print('playername')`, "Patrick Rodgers" appears

Comment: Just running your code, prints every name for me. https://repl.it/@jimtje/BriefVirtuousRefactoring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the data, try to define list and append each value:

```
players = []
for table in sg_ttg.find_all('tbody'):
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        player = row.find('td', class_= 'player-name').text.strip()
        players.append(player)

print(players)
```

Comment: This worked great thanks! However, now it is grabbing the names with '\n in front and behind the names. I'm new to Python so sorry if this is a silly question but how can I remove this?